# App not appearing in play store when I search

Tags: android, search, google-play

I published a game recently on play store. Initially the name of app was "Up" but after an hour or two I thought "Up" name would be very generic so decided to change the name to "Ship Up". My app is appearing as "Ship Up" in market and all places and I am also able to view my app if I open the link(https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ids.up.android) and even if I search com.ids.up.android. But when I try searching "Ship Up" or "Ship Up IDSstudio" my app doesn't shows up in search results. On the other hand if I search "Up IDSstudio" I am able to find the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to include keywords in the description field for your app. For example:

```
Ship Up

Description

The Ship needs your help! 
...
Keywords: Ship Up, IDSstudio, etc.
```

It will take a few hours to a day for Google Play servers to refresh with your changes. So wait for about 24 hours and search again in Google Play.

Comment: Ship Up keyword is already included as you can see in the description: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ids.up.android
It havn't been 24 hrs. since I published the game but I am really getting worried up as this didn't happened when I published apps before.

Comment: No, you'll need to add the tag `Keywords` in the description field that is then followed by the keywords you want - preferably the first one should be your app's name.

Comment: Is adding Keyword allowed in Play Store? Becoz I read somewhere it is against Play Store Policies

Comment: It's allow provided you don't include keywords that do not describe your app, and you are not excessive with the keywords. This is done so as to prevent apps from promoting themselves scrupulously.

Comment: Ok thanx. Will mark this as answer once the problem gets solved.

Comment: The problem was not this that I needed to wait 24hrs. As I later realised "Ship Up"(including quotation marks) was showing my app. Adding Keywords and people ratings helped me climb the search reasults and now the game is comming at 13th position when I search Ship Up.

Comment: Now Google rejects such updates due to "don't allow apps with misleading, improperly formatted, non-descriptive, irrelevant, excessive, or inappropriate metadata"